# Pythonic way of creating a factory with object creation restriction

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preface: I'm trying to guard against misuse (mostly by myself) and not malicious use (thus the "consenting adults" principle does not apply).

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```py
class Foo(Base):
    ...

class Bar(Base):
    ...

class FooBarFactory:
    __bar_cache = BarCache()

    @classmethod
    def createFoo(cls):
        return Foo()

    @classmethod
    def createBar(cls, key):
        return cls.__bar_cache.get_or_create(key)
```

The problem is that I want to restrict `Foo` and `Bar` creation to only `FooBarFactory`'s methods. So,

```py
foo = FooBarFactory.createFoo()  # OK
foo = Foo()  # raise AssertionError('use factory method')
```

How do I do that? One option that I see is to put `Foo` and `Bar` inside the factory class (to ensure that code users know about the factory). But that would produce a bloated class definition. Another option is to do something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    _trade_secret = 'super_secret_foo_message_dont_use'
    def __init__(self, secret):
        assert secret == Foo._trade_secret
        ...

class FooBarFactory:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def createFoo(cls):
        # suppress private field access warning here
        return Foo(Foo._trade_secret)
```

But that also looks clumsy and verbose.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "One option that I see is to put Foo and Bar inside the factory class, but I want to check their type, so it's not an acceptable solution." Why is it not acceptable? And how does putting Foo and Bar inside help here to begin with? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Hmm, I assumed that internal classes can't be easily accessed from the outside. But apparently it's not true. At least it would direct the class user to read the documentation in the factory class. I still don't like the solution because it implies all kinds of readability problems: bloated file, unnecessary prefixes, etc.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to prevent, *exactly*?

Comment: You could define the classes inside the factory class methods themselves. Doesn't solve your problems of readability loss and file bloat though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I'm trying to prevent an accidental use of `Foo()` "constructor" by an unsuspecting code user. Also I'm trying to make it without making the code unnecessarily complex and unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

If your factory can do it, then everyone else can. There is no solution for this in python as noone has special privileges.

On the other hand, while you can't force people to code properly, you can make it hard for them to screw up:

```py
class Foo:
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs):
      raise NotImplementedError("Use the factory.")

    @classmethod
    def _new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      foo = super().__new__(cls)
      foo.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      return foo


class Factory:
    @staticmethod
    def createFoo(*args, **kwargs):
        return Foo._new(*args, **kwargs)


Factory.createFoo() # works fine
Foo()               # raises an exception
```

But if your users want to call `Foo._new` then nothing will stop them from creating an object without "your permission".

Comment: > "If your factory can do it, then everyone else can" - 


I understand that, that's why I wrote that I'm trying to guard the code against misuse, not malicious/deliberate use.


Your solution does solve the problem, but seems more verbose than the last option in my question?

Comment: The advantage I see in my answer is that it never creates any instance when Foo() is called, while your solution does. It just look a bit cleaner to me to prevent instantiation because that's your first goal. Then we add some more code to allow instantiation via an alternative method (`_new`). The difference is suttle, I'm not sure mine is better overall. You can also replace your `secret` assertion inside `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys._getframe(1)` to get the caller's frame, where you can obtain the caller's `cls` local variable and the caller's function name. To make sure someone isn't calling `Foo.__new__` from a different class with the same name and the same method name, you can check if the filename of the caller's frame is the same as the filename of the current frame:

```
import sys

class Foo:
    def __new__(cls):
        caller_frame = sys._getframe(1)
        if 'cls' not in caller_frame.f_locals or \
            caller_frame.f_locals["cls"].__name__ != 'FooBarFactory' or \
            caller_frame.f_code.co_name != 'createFoo' or \
            caller_frame.f_code.co_filename != sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_filename:
            raise RuntimeError('Foo must be instantiated via the FooBarFactory.createFoo method.')
        print('Foo OK')
        return super().__new__(cls)

class FooBarFactory:
    @classmethod
    def createFoo(cls):
        return Foo()
```

so that:

```
FooBarFactory.createFoo()
```

outputs:

```
Foo OK
```

and:

```
Foo()
```

outputs:

```
RuntimeError: Foo must be instantiated via the FooBarFactory.createFoo method.
```

Or since you supposedly control your own file, and the `FooBarFactor.createFoo` method is supposedly the only caller you have in the file that instantiates `Foo`, the filename check alone should just be enough:

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls):
        if sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_filename != sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_filename:
            raise RuntimeError('Foo must be instantiated via the FooBarFactory.createFoo method.')
        return super().__new__(cls)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! But if I create a class/method with the right names, then I can create `Foo` instances myself, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional check for the filename so it's practically not fakable.

Comment: Yes practically :D, in the end (I'm pretty sure) you'll never be able to have any guarantee so I find the simplest answer better. I only see two options, either the user want to break your code (in which case you are probably doomed) or the user is peaceful and he will stop as soon as he sees that `Foo()` doesn't work. But I like your idea anyway. Do you think there is a way to remove the string constants like `"FooBarFactory"`? Maybe by moving `Foo` inside `FooBarFactory.createFoo`, that may look cleaner. You could also put the long if inside a function (to hide the mess).

Comment: `foo = object.__new__(Foo)`

Comment: And also naming the different conditions and then perform something like `any(...)` or `all(...)`.

Comment: Hmm, that makes me think, is there a way to instantiate a Foo object if Foo is defined inside `createFoo`? I think this must be possible, but I'm not sure how yet :p

Comment: @cglacet yes, `type(some_instance)()` will give you the type, but worse, it would break the type system IMO. Every *instance* would be a distinct type, since `Foo` would be a unique class each time

Comment: Yes that's indeed a problem if we want to write things like `type(Factory.createFoo()) == type(Factory.createFoo())`

Comment: @cglacet I can't think of an elegant way to obtain the factory class's name from `Foo` (the only option I can think of is to use `ast.NodeVistor` to traverse the code tree to find the only class with a method that calls `Foo`, but it really is an overkill), and defining `Foo` in a method introduces other problems as juanpa.arrivillaga has pointed out. But now come to think of it, since you supposedly own the file that has the definitions of `Foo` and `FooBarFactory`, and `createFoo` should be the only caller to `Foo` in the file, the filename check alone should be enough. Don't you think?

Comment: Huh, that's an interesting approach! Do you know what are the performance implications of inspecting the stack?

Also, I don't see an easy way to put this code in the `Base` class, because it's `__init__` is called from the `Foo`'s `__init__`.

Comment: I think this solution could work inside `__new__` too.

Comment: As for modifying the filename on the fly I don't know how to do it, but I know read only attributes can be modified.

Comment: @EvilTosha Indeed `inspect.stack()` is rather slow. I've updated my answer to use `sys._getframe()` instead so that it's about 6000 times faster in my testing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point about the `__new__` method. I've updated my answer to use it instead.

Comment: @cglacet I don't think it's possible to modify the filename in the code stack from within the normal Python API.

Comment: @blhsing my point is that all this rigamarole can be easily bypassed by doing `foo = object.__new__(Foo)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops I did not notice your use of the `object` class. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution in addition to the various options in other answers:

```py
class Base:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        assert kwargs.get('secret') == Factory._secret, 'use the factory'
        return super(Base, cls).__new__(cls)

class Foo(Base):
    def __init__(self, param, **kwargs):
        self.param = param

class Factory:
    _secret = 'super_secret_dont_copy'

    @classmethod
    def create_foo(cls, param):
        return Foo(param=param, secret=cls._secret)
```

Now,

```py
foo = Foo(23)  # AssertionError
foo = Factory.create_foo(23)  # OK
```

The solution allows to minimize extra code for additional sub-classes of `Base` (the validation code is encapsulated in the `Base` class), but it has a drawback of having to add `**kwargs` to all sub-classes' `__init__`.